# I can't get a graphic to change according to user inputs

Tags: python, input

I am trying to create a maze game in Python, but when it should move the player icon according to user commands and either complete the game or end it because a user hit a wall nothing happens. It only keeps asking for input from the user without changing.

[image: progam code snippet]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Add code as text, not as an image, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.